# How to create a function which Iterates over multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, for-loop

So I'm creating a series of column mappings, I can do this manually like so

```
#Produces a list of dictionaries
def create_seed_dict(column, dataset):
    seed_col_vals = dataset[column].values.tolist()
    seed_col_keys =[column] * (len(seed_col_vals))
    seed_col_map = list(zip(seed_col_keys, seed_col_vals))
    seed_dict = []
    for k,v in seed_col_map:
        diction = {}
        diction[k] = v 
        seed_dict.append(diction)
    return seed_dict, seed_col_map

#Create dummy dataframe
num = [1, 2, 3] 
color = ['red', 'white', 'black'] 
value = [255, 256, 257] 
dict = {'Number': num, 'Color': color, 'Score': value}  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

Num_seed_Dict,Num_map = create_seed_dict('Number', df)
print(Num_seed_Dict)
-----------------------------
Out[1]: [{'Number': 1}, {'Number': 2}, {'Number': 3}]
```

The function produces a mapping of a value and its column. Great, now I want to make this more general.

Currently, if I needed to map 2 columns for example I run the following:

```
num_vals = df['Number'].values.tolist()
num_keys =['Number'] * (len(num_vals))
num_map = list(zip(num_keys, num_vals))
numDict = []
for k,v in num_map:
    diction = {}
    diction[k] = v 
    numDict.append(diction)
    

color_vals = df['Color'].values.tolist()
color_keys =['Color'] * (len(color_vals))
color_map = list(zip(color_keys, color_vals))
colorDict = []
for k,v in num_map:
    diction = {}
    diction[k] = v 
    colorDict.append(diction)

colorNum_Dict = []
for (f,b) in zip(num_map, color_map):
    diction = {}
    diction[f[0]] = f[1] 
    diction[b[0]] = b[1] 
    colorNum_Dict.append(diction)
    
print(colorNum_Dict)
-----------------------------
[{'Number': 1, 'Color': 'red'}, {'Number': 2, 'Color': 'white'}, {'Number': 3, 'Color': 'black'}]
```

---

Works as well but not ideal if I have a lot of columns. My question is how do I make the first function valid for more than 1 column?

My main issue is that the `for (f,b) in zip(num_map, color_map):` line, I dont know how to dynamically define (f,b..) to match the number of `_maps` I have within zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to accept them in a tuple.  The Pythonic way you create an arbitrary quantity of variables is with a sequence.  `zip` already returns a list for you.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [True, False, False]
c = ['x', 'y', 'z']
abc = [a, b, c]

for several in zip(*abc):
    print(several)
```

Output:

```
(1, True, 'x')
(2, False, 'y')
(3, False, 'z')
```

Thereafter, you can use len(several) as the controlling value to work with those items.  If what you want is to use the first element as a key, and the rest as the value:

```
diction[several[0]] = lsit(several[1:])
```

If you want to enter each element as a key, with the others as values, just iterate through `several`, using the indicated element as the key, and the others as the value.  If you're unclear how to do that, look up `slice notation`, or how to remove one element from a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your dataframe together, you can use the `to_dict` method to get the same result:

```
>>> print(df)
   Number  Color  Score
0       1    red    255
1       2  white    256
2       3  black    257

# Select columns, then call `to_dict`
>>> color_num_records = df[["Number", "Color"]].to_dict("records")
>>> print(color_num_records)
[{'Number': 1, 'Color': 'red'}, {'Number': 2, 'Color': 'white'}, {'Number': 3, 'Color': 'black'}]
```